# Xamarin forms date picker android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I'm using Xamarin Forms for android and IOS.
and I need to make the year section in the date picker dialogue Clickable.

[image]

because I can not select the year it is only months selection.
the problems with this is if I want to go 10 years behind I need to change the month page 120 times which make a very poor user experience.

Comment: Nothing happens when you click on "February 2016"? That should bring up another popup, that has a way to change year.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve
well, it does not work and I feel a little vibration on my device while click on the year indicating that there is a event but I have no idea how to use it or even call it.

Comment: Did you add a min or max date like here https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker#datepicker-and-layout or show some code . This is hard to help , @ToolmakerSteve is write click on the year and change it.

Comment: Please click the year label (for example: `2016`). I tried on several android devices with different android versions, but couldn't reproduce this problem.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT
thanks for your help.
I was clicking on the header text which represents the date not the year

Comment: So, is it working now,right? As a summary, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please click the year label (for example: `2016`).

Once you click on the year label, a list of years will display.Then you can scroll the year list and select the special year you want.